# update-alternatives per user

Tags: 14.04, command-line, software-installation

i know that with `update-alternatives` admin can choose the current version of app. but is there something similar for non-root users. so they can switch their current version without affecting other users and without requiring root access?

Comment: Yes but it is not really user-friendly to set up: https://serverfault.com/questions/631447/how-to-use-update-alternatives-per-user

Comment: What about `alias foo=foo.v3; foo`?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I wanted to chime in with a blatant promotion for the tool I just released that helps you configure per-user (or even per-shell !) alternatives:

- https://github.com/TekWizely/my-alternatives

You can initialize a shell-specific setup:

```
$ eval "$( my-alternatives init)"
```

Or you can initialize a long-lived user-level setup:

```
# run this once
$ eval "$( my-alternatives init ~/my-alts )"

# place this in your startup scripts
$ eval "$( my-alternatives shellenv ~/my-alts )"
```

Once configured, setting up a user-local alternative is as easy as:

```
# equivalent to 'update-alternatives --config <name>'
$ my-alternatives config <name>
```

**NOTE:** At the time of this posting, *my-alternatives* was just released.  As such, only `init` and `config` logic has been built.  Other features will come later.